# Lisp Recreating a Temporary Variable

Tags: lisp, let

I'm having a bit of trouble with Lisp.  What i'm attempting to do, is keep track of the amount of times a number appears in x number of lists.  However, running this over and over again, lisp isn't recreating the variable, but using the ending value from the last time I called the function.  So I'm wondering how can I get past the 'binding' powers of let?

So, I've got some list like this

```
    (((8 7) (3)) ((8 3) (2)) ((7 3) (6)) ((7 2) (8)) ((6 7) (4 1))
 ((6 6) (4 1)) ((6 2) (2)) ((5 6) (3)) ((5 3) (8 3)) ((4 6) (4))
 ((4 4) (6)) ((4 1) (7)) ((3 7) (5 3)) ((3 4) (1)) ((3 3) (3)) ((3 1) (9))
 ((2 7) (7)) ((2 5) (2)) ((2 2) (5 2)) ((1 7) (1)) ((1 6) (6 1))
 ((1 1) (2 1)) ((1 0) (3)) ((0 7) (8 1)) ((0 5) (6)) ((0 3) (9 6))
 ((0 1) (1)))
```

Then I'm calling some function like this, (declaring var here doesn't seem to do anything, past the initial function call)...  I guess some kind of binding from let.

```
(defun counter (possibleValues)
(let ((var '(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)))
    (loop for i from 0 to (list-length possibleValues) do
        (loop for j in (cdr (nth i possibleValues)) do
             (loop for k in j do
              (incf (nth k var)))))
    var))
```

So I can run my list through the function and get something like

```
(0 8 5 6 3 2 5 2 3 2)
```

Each position referring to the number found in the list.  So the value 8 would refer to how many times 1 was found in all the lists (i'm considering the second list only).  Now the problem....  run it twice and...

```
(0 16 10 12 6 4 10 4 6 4)
```

I was using an associative list earlier, but in trying to figure this out and keep things simple, i'm now using a list.  I guess another question I have is, how can I create associative list elements on the fly?  I don't like declaring 'var' like that, but I'm just trying to get around 'let' for the moment.  I haven't had much luck with 'setq' or 'setf' either....

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you are iterating over I and accessing the list with (NTH I ...) ??? That looks REALLY BAD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the initialization form for VAR to be an expression that creates new lists, such as `(make-list 10 :initial-element 0)` or even `(list 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)`.

Basically, do not ever use quoted objects if you have intentions on modifying them, as the consequences are undefined if you do. In fact, evaluating  that function definition gives a warning about that:

```
; in: LAMBDA NIL
;     (INCF (NTH K VAR))
; --> LET* 
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:%SETNTH #:TMP5 #:TMP4 #:NEW3)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   Destructive function SB-KERNEL:%SETNTH called on constant data.
;   See also:
;     The ANSI Standard, Special Operator QUOTE
;     The ANSI Standard, Section 3.2.2.3
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
```

Comment: @jello It's good form to accept this as the correct answer :-)